# cakephp 2.3 ajax form submission

Tags: php, ajax, jquery, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I am trying to create a simple form to submit data to the database with ajax. here is my view

```
  <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery', FALSE); ?> 
<?php echo $this->Html->script('validation', FALSE); ?>
  <div id="success"></div>
  <h2>Contact Us</h2>

  <?php
   echo $this->Form->create();
   echo $this->Form->input('name', array('id'=>'name'));
   echo $this->Form->input('email', array('id'=>'email'));
   echo $this->Form->input('message', array('id'=>'message'));
   echo $this->Js->submit('Send', array(
'before'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeIn'),
'success'=>$this->Js->get('#sending')->effect('fadeOut'),
'update'=>'#success'
 ));
 echo $this->Form->end();
  ?>
   <div id="sending" style="display: none; background-color: lightgreen;">Sending...</div>
```

**Controller**

```
    class MessagesController extends AppController{

public $helpers = array('Js');
public $components = array('RequestHandler');

public function index(){

  if(!empty($this->data)){
      if($this->Message->save($this->data)){
          if($this->request->isAjax()){
             $this->render('success','ajax');
          }else{


         $this->Session->setFlash('Message sent');
         $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'));
      }
      }
  }
 }

 }
```

it is not sending the form through ajax.. actually i am new in cakephp and this is my first time i am using ajax in cakephp. and also i want to know that  can i use codeigniter or simple php similar  syntax of form submission in cake php. for example  like this

```
  <script>

 $('#btn').click(function(event) {
       form = $("#form").serialize();

     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "<?php  echo site_url('categoryController/addCategory'); ?>",
       data: form,

       success: function(data){
           $('.modal').modal('hide');
           $(".success").fadeIn(500).delay(2000).fadeOut(500);
           $("#form")[0].reset();
           //Unterminated String constant fixed
       }

     });
     event.preventDefault();
     return false;  //stop the actual form post !important!

  });

</script>
```

Comment: can you tell me more specifically what is the problem ? Can you see the ajax request using firebug ?

Comment: sorry i got my answer actually i was missing jquery.js file

Comment: If you found the answer, can you delete the question (since it was a file problem and not much to do with coding)? Or answer it yourself and accept it?

Comment: @Nunser / Moyed can you post a version without the Js helper, in pure jquery?

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. I was missing `jquery.js` file.